# FLUTTER IOS: my app have not the same name in spotlight

Tags: ios, flutter

I have built an app with a bundle name "MYAPP", but when I search "MYAPP" on my phone it show me my app called "runner". Do you know how to fix it ?

ps: If I search it manualy it is called "MYAPP"